# wso2 API Manager with Analytics

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I installed wso2 API Manager with Analytics onto my windows laptop.
I get the below exception when I run the bat file

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-08 20:31:02,357]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.SparkScriptCAppDeployer} -  Deploying spark script: APIM_LAST_ACCESS_TIME_SCRIPT.xml for tenant : -1234 {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.SparkScriptCAppDeployer}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-08 20:31:02,473]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.AbstractQuartzTaskManager} -  Task scheduled: [-1234][ANALYTICS_SPARK][APIM_LAST_ACCESS_TIME_SCRIPT] {org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.AbstractQuartzTaskManager}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-08 20:31:02,478] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager} -  Error while deploying stored cApp : org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager$PendingApplication@74bf5355 {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager}
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid input path generated, the input cannot contain backtracking path elements
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.core.util.GenericUtils.checkAndReturnPath(GenericUtils.java:787)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.dataservice.core.AnalyticsDataPurgingDeployer.registerPurgingTasks(AnalyticsDataPurgingDeployer.java:147)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.dataservice.core.AnalyticsDataPurgingDeployer.deployArtifacts(AnalyticsDataPurgingDeployer.java:79)
    at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager.deployCarbonApp(ApplicationManager.java:263)
    at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager.tryDeployPendingCarbonApps(ApplicationManager.java:131)
    at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager.registerDeploymentHandler(ApplicationManager.java:122)
    at org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.AppDeployerServiceComponent.setAppHandler(AppDeployerServiceComponent.java:153)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ComponentReference.bind(ComponentReference.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.bindReference(ServiceComponentProp.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.dynamicBind(InstanceProcess.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
```

Second time, I tried wso2server.bat -Dsetup and I am still getting the same issue.

Is this is a known issue? How to fix this.

Comment: Please post your entire error trace.

Comment: updated the logs in the original request

Comment: I assume this is a bug within wso2 api manager with analytics

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in APIM-Analytics server in windows. The same issue is [fixed](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-analytics/commit/37781ae1c32e625244e98bc928bf4e3afae6a9d0) in DAS 3.1.0, but not in APIM-Analytics 2.0.0.

But you have 3 options to get rid of this.

1) Use DAS 3.1.0 instead of APIM-Analytics server, and [configure it for APIM analytics](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Installing+WSO2+APIM+Analytics+Features). Then you can install car file in it.

2) Disable purging by commenting out `<!-- purging -->` section of `./artifacts.xml` inside car file. Please note that disable purging will accumulate data over time.

3) Use the online version of API Manager - [WSO2 API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud) - that does not have that issue.